# How can I push the modified static field data in the array returned by the function after each change of the static field?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is an example. I have class `WalmartCart` and I can't change it.

```
class WalmartCart {
    static cart = []
    putItem(item){
        WalmartCart.cart.push(item)
    }
}
```

And I need to have a function `func` which accepts the class as input and returns the array with modified items in `static cart` in `WalmartCart`.

```
const func = (WalmartCart) => {}
```

So, the result should look like this

```
let result = func(WalmartCart) // !!
let wal = new WalmartCart()

wal.putItem( {'1': 1} )
wal.putItem( {'2': 2} )
wal.putItem( {'3': '3'} )

console.log(result) 

// result =  [
//    {'1': 1, 'some new data': 'new data'}, 
//    {'2': 2, 'some new data': 'new data'}, 
//    {'3': '3', 'some new data': 'new data'}
// ]
```

The whole catch is that the function `func` can be called only once **before** putting the items in the `static cart`.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: just `return Walmart.cart`, it will assign a reference to the array to `result` which will reflect all changes made to the other references to the same array. see: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) and read the documentation [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

You can return `WalmartCart.cart` directly in `func`

Like many other programming languages, Javascript also has [call-by-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) which is using a reference as a medium to the actual values.

```js
class WalmartCart {
    static cart = [] //reference value
    putItem(item){
        WalmartCart.cart.push(item)
    }
}

const func = (WalmartCart) => {
  return WalmartCart.cart
}

let result = func(WalmartCart) //now `result` and `WalmartCart.cart` have the same reference value

console.log(`Is result and WalmartCart.cart is the same reference value: ${result === WalmartCart.cart}`)

let wal = new WalmartCart()

//`WalmartCart.cart` modification means `result` modification as well
wal.putItem( {'1': 1} ) 
wal.putItem( {'2': 2} )
wal.putItem( {'3': '3'} )

console.log(result)
```

Comment: some explanation about referencing would greatly improve this answer

Answer (score 0):

Just `const func = (T) => T.cart`

live demo:

```js
const func = (T) => T.cart

class WalmartCart {
    static cart = []
    putItem(item){
        WalmartCart.cart.push(item)
    }
}

let result = func(WalmartCart)
let wal = new WalmartCart()
wal.putItem( {'1': 1} )
wal.putItem( {'2': 2} )
wal.putItem( {'3': '3'} )

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```